# Функция преобразование Фурье(DFT) работает не правильно?

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

```
def dft(list_of_values):
    HEIGHT = max(list(map(lambda x: abs(x), list_of_values)))
    MAX_HERZT = len(list_of_values)

    total = list()

    for hertz in range(1, MAX_HERZT + 1):
        interval_total = list()
        for values in enumerate(list_of_values):
            interval_total.append(values[1] * HEIGHT * math.cos(math.pi * 2 * values[0] / hertz) - values[1] * HEIGHT * math.sin(math.pi * 2 * values[0] / hertz))

        total.append(sum(interval_total))

    total = list(map(lambda x: x / max(total), total))


    g = list()
    for i in total:
        g.append(i)
        g.append(i)
    return g

k = 100

b = list()
for i in range(k):
    b.append(i)
    b.append(i)
b = b[1:] + [k - 1]

a = [random.randint(-1, 1) for i in range(k)]
plot = pg.plot(b, dft(a), fillLevel=0, brush=(0, 214, 0, 100))
plot.plot([0, k], [0, 0], pen=(255, 255, 255))

plot_2 = pg.plot([i for i in range(len(a))], [int(i) for i in np.fft.fft(a)], fillLevel=0, brush=(30, 144, 255))
plot_2.plot([0, k], [0, 0], pen=(255, 255, 255))

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
w.resize(1200, 800)
layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
w.setLayout(layout)
layout.addWidget(plot, 0, 0)
layout.addWidget(plot_2, 0, 1)
w.show()
app.exec()
```

Результат моей функция dft, отличается от результата функции numpy.fft.fft, при одинаковых входных данных.
Что я сделал не так

Comment: В смысле вы хотите, чтобы мы вам протестировали функцию?? Так это не работает. Это вы должны сказать, почему вы думаете, что функция работает неправильно, предоставить нам тестовые данные, объяснить, почему вы так думаете, а дальше можно разбираться, что здесь не так.

Comment: Так, уже лучше. Теперь **приведите конкретные примеры**: у меня получается то-то, а вот этой функцией получается то-то, при вот таких то входных данных (если данные большие - ссылка, где их можно скачать).

Comment: Я не понимаю, что делается в функции. Например, результатом должен быть массив комплексных чисел. Что означает строчка с разностью косинуса и синуса? Возьмите формулу хоть [в википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%B5#%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8B_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) и посчитайте по ней. В формуле i - это мнимая единица